# Building WCF Service in VS2010

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

All,

I have a WCF Service I inherited from someone else. 
When I make a Build either Debug or Release, the binaries go in the same folder.
I was under the impression that Visual Studio 2010 always has two folders, Debug and Release and depending on the type of the build the binaries go to the appropriate folder.
Any ideas?

Rgds,
MK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Build tab of the project's Properties. There you'll see the Output path, which might be set to the same folder for both Debug and Release Configuration (selectable through the drop-down on the top of the page).